# PhoneGapHtml5_Problem

Tags: iphone, webview, cordova

Just wanted to ask u how do we link HTML file in PhoneGap Applications.As u know that in when we create PhoneGap application one Html file comes with it i just want to know how it is linked to the application so that i could add more Html files to it and use it ib webview

Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please control click on any web view delegate method placed in App delegate method then in the new class which appears after contrl clicking make following changes...

> - (NSString*) wwwFolderName {     return @"www"; }
> - (NSString*) startPage {     return @"index.html"; }

In these 2 functions i.e wht html file u want to attach in your phone gap u can write the name in start page function as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple pages you can just link to them as normal. (Remember, use relative links).

It's hower normal to use only 1 page in phonegap application. 1 page that uses hidden divs.
 Don't really know why, besides the fact symbian only supports 1 page with acces to the device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but do u have any idea how the first page is linked as there is nothing i can find in (.h and .m) files.There must be something somewhere how the page is actually linked to be shown in web-view

Answer (score 0):

Just place your HTML files and other resouces (like images, scripts, etc) **inside the "www" folder** :) as Erik said, just link them as yoiu normally do. You don't need to edit any Objective-C files (like .m or .h).
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGapDelegate.m is where the phonegap settings are stored. The PhoneGapViewController.m is where the UIWebView is bound to the xib.